# How to validate file extension using jQuery validation engine

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I have tried the following code to validate a file that file type should be csv.

```
"validateMIME":  {
    "func": function(field, rules, i, options){     
    var fileInput = field[0].files[0];
    var MimeFilter = new RegExp(rules[3],'i');
    if (fileInput) {
        return MimeFilter.test(fileInput.type);
    } else { return true;}
  },
"alertText": "* Only csv file is allowed."
},
```

Firfox only works if use below code to validate

```
<input type="file" name="csvfile" class="validate[required, custom[validateMIME[text/text/comma-separated-values]]]">
```

I tried the below code, no browser works

```
<input type="file" name="csvfile" class="validate[required, custom[validateMIME[text/text/csv]]]">
```

Anyone suggest me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: The "jQuery Validation Engine" and the "jQuery Validate plugin" are two totally different projects.  Please pay attention to the tag descriptions.  Edited.  Thanks.